# "live bytes" different on simulator versus device

Tags: ios, memory, memory-management, instruments, ram

I have a program that is showing, in the allocations instrument, approx. 72 MB of "live bytes" but when I run the profiling on my iPod touch, it shows 6 MB.  I don't understand why the vast difference.  Can anybody please explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that the iOS Simulator is a *simulator*, **not an emulator**.

The iOS Simulator works by compiling your iOS application to x86 code, and linking it against a set of system frameworks which simulate their iOS equivalents on a desktop computer. These frameworks are, of necessity, not identical to those that you'd find on "real" iOS -- they are, after all, compiled for a different CPU architecture, and are "talking to" desktop hardware, not a handheld device.

Knowing this, it should be understandable that some aspects of application performance may be radically different on the Simulator than on a real device. Keep this in mind, and test your code early and often on real hardware!

Comment: Thank you.  That is a much clearer answer than below - I assumed I was dealing with a simulator; this is very helpful info because I have been trying to find an apparent "leak" for days, when there actually is none; on the real hardware, it works fine.